# Starting the week on Monday with isoWeekday()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm creating a calendar where I print out weeks in a tabular format. One requirement is that I be able to start the weeks either on Monday or Sunday, as per some user option. I'm having a hard time using moment's [isoWeekday](http://momentjs.com/docs/?codekitCB=401206465.298830#/get-set/iso-weekday/) method.

```
// Start of some date range. Can be any day of the week.
var startOfPeriod = moment("2013-06-23T00:00:00"),

    // We begin on the start of the first week.
    // Mon Tues Wed Thur Fri Sat Sun
    // 20  21   22  23   24  25  26
    begin = moment(startOfPeriod).isoWeekday(1); // will pull from user setting

console.log(begin.isoWeekday()); // 1 - all good

// Let's get the beginning of this first week, respecting the isoWeekday
begin.startOf('week');

console.log(begin.isoWeekday()); // 7 - what happened ???

// Get column headers
for (var i=0; i<7; i++) {
    console.log(begin.format('ddd')); // I want Monday first!
    begin.add('d', 1);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxAUd/)

**EDIT** I misunderstood what `isoWeekday` was actually doing. I thought it set the "which day of the week is the first day of the week" variable (that doesn't exist). What it actually does is simply changes the day of the week, just like `moment.weekday()`, but uses a 1-7 range instead of the 0-6.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

You just need to replace `begin.startOf('isoWeek');` with `begin.startOf('week');`.

Comment: `startOf('week')` depends on the current locale where Sunday obviously marks the start of the week in your case. `startOf('iweek')` will get the ISO start of the week, which is Monday. But you're right, I didn't find any documentation on the official site ...

Comment: Current version of moment.js is using `isoweek`.

Comment: Edited according to @savinger's comment and the [current docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) :)

Comment: `isoWeek`, with a capital W, in the latest version

Comment: Documented here: [Start of Time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)

Answer (score 26):

This way you can set the initial day of the week.

```
moment.locale('en', {
    week: {
        dow: 6
    }
});
moment.locale('en');
```

Make sure to use it with `moment().weekday(1);` instead of moment.isoWeekday(1)

Comment: Just update, that new release requires `doy` (First day of the year) as well. It worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Call `startOf` before `isoWeekday`.

```
var begin = moment(date).startOf('week').isoWeekday(1);
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PxAUd/1/)

Comment: This does not work properly. For today's date, 2016-09-05 it returns 2016-08-29 as a begin date of the week which is not true, because today is Monday (iso week).

the proper answer is already accepted.

Comment: Don't understand why is is so popular because it is obviously wrong. startOf('week') returns Sunday (of the past Week) and setting it then to Monday sets it one week to early.

Answer (score 2):

thought I would add this for any future peeps.   It will always make sure that its monday if needed, can also be used to always ensure sunday.  For me I always need monday, but local is dependant on the machine being used, and this is an easy fix:

```
var begin = moment().isoWeekday(1).startOf('week');
var begin2 = moment().startOf('week');
// could check to see if day 1 = Sunday  then add 1 day
// my mac on bst still treats day 1 as sunday    

var firstDay = moment().startOf('week').format('dddd') === 'Sunday' ?     
moment().startOf('week').add('d',1).format('dddd DD-MM-YYYY') : 
moment().startOf('week').format('dddd DD-MM-YYYY');

document.body.innerHTML = '<b>could be monday or sunday depending on client: </b><br />' + 
begin.format('dddd DD-MM-YYYY') + 
'<br /><br /> <b>should be monday:</b> <br>' + firstDay + 
'<br><br> <b>could also be sunday or monday </b><br> ' + 
begin2.format('dddd DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: possible shortcut moment().isoWeekday(1).startOf('isoweek').format('dddd DD MM YYYY')

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more generic solution for any given weekday. [Working demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4y2t23e6/1/)

```
var myIsoWeekDay = 2; // say our weeks start on tuesday, for monday you would type 1, etc.

var startOfPeriod = moment("2013-06-23T00:00:00"),

// how many days do we have to substract?
var daysToSubtract = moment(startOfPeriod).isoWeekday() >= myIsoWeekDay ?
    moment(startOfPeriod).isoWeekday() - myIsoWeekDay :
    7 + moment(startOfPeriod).isoWeekday() - myIsoWeekDay;

// subtract days from start of period
var begin = moment(startOfPeriod).subtract('d', daysToSubtract);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```js
var begin = moment(date).isoWeekday(1).startOf('isoWeek');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!-- Starting Date From Monday -->
var moment= moment.js;
<!-- Javascript Code -->

var begin = moment().startOf('week').add('days', 1)


<!--  React JS  Code -->

var begin = moment().startOf('week').add(2, 'days');
```

Answer (score -2):

For those who want `isoWeek` to be the default you can modify moment's behaviour as such:

```
const moment = require('moment');
const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(moment());

const {startOf, endOf} = proto;
proto.startOf = function(period) {
  if (period === 'week') {
    period = 'isoWeek';
  }
  return startOf.call(this, period);
};
proto.endOf = function(period) {
  if (period === 'week') {
    period = 'isoWeek';
  }
  return endOf.call(this, period);
};
```

Now you can simply use `someDate.startOf('week')` without worrying you'll get sunday or having to think about whether to use `isoweek` or `isoWeek` etc.

Plus you can store this in a variable like `const period = 'week'` and use it safely in `subtract()` or `add()` operations, e.g. `moment().subtract(1, period).startOf(period);`. This won't work with period being `isoWeek`.