# Get week number of year considering different first day of week

Tags: momentjs

I can do `new moment().week()` to get the week number for the current day.

When the current day is a Sunday/Monday which can be set as first day of week by my user, **how can I do something like this to get the week index with momentJS:**

```
 new moment().firstDayOfWeek(1).week() // monday
```

OR

```
new moment().firstDayOfWeek('monday').week();
```

I do not want to load or change a locale setting via including .js files...

My user can sit in the United States where first day of week is seen as Sunday.

But my user is from Europe so he wants to have European calendar settings where a week starts on Monday.

Comment: I think your answer lies here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875649/moment-js-starting-the-week-on-monday-with-isoweekday

Comment: Seems your link with the fiddle is the solution:  begin = moment(date).startOf('week').isoWeekday(0); Change 0 (sunday to 1 (monday) returns different week data in the fiddle.So it works even with momentjs 2.9.0 => http://jsfiddle.net/PxAUd/1/ Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this answers your question. If you change the loop to output 2 weeks and add the week to the output you can see Sun 23-6-13 is always the start of WK: 26 regardless of the value passed to isoWeek http://jsfiddle.net/PxAUd/301/