# Get the First Weekday of the Month with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have some code that gets the first weekday of the month using moment.js (that is a requirement) which looks like this:

```
dateStart: function() { 
    var first = moment().startOf('month');
    switch(first.day()) {
        case 6:
            return first.add(2, 'days');
        case 0:
            return first.add(1, 'days');
        default:
            return first;
    };
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Checkout this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875649/moment-js-starting-the-week-on-monday-with-isoweekday

Comment: I think your method is pretty clever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first day is sunday or saturday (`first.day() % 6 === 0`) then return next monday (`first.day(1)`):

```
function dateStart() {
  var first = moment().startOf('month');
  return first.day() % 6 === 0 ? first.add(1, 'day').day(1) : first;
}
```

As mentioned in comments `first.day(1)` can return monday in previous month. This can happen if the first day of the month is saturday. To be sure you get monday from the week in current month just add 1 to the weekend date.

Comment: Ahem, this does not work. The `first.day(1)` will get the monday of the same week as the first day of the month, which might be in the previous month. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/yd5qaLa1/.

Comment: thanks it help me :) but, how to get the last day of weekdays of the last month???(this will be december)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I guess you just have to get the first day of the month and then add days until the day is a working day. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/4rfrg4c0/2/

```
function get_first_working_day (year, month) {

    // get the first day of the specified month and year
    var first_working_day = new moment([year, month])

    // add days until the day is a working day
    while (first_working_day.day() % 6 == 0) {
        first_working_day = first_working_day.add(1, 'day')
    }

    // return the day
    return first_working_day
}

// tests
$('.september').append(get_first_working_day(2016, 8).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'))
$('.october').append(get_first_working_day(2016, 9).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'))
```

Comment: Really old answer I know. You may not use the site still... but....

If I wanted it to exclude Wednesday how would I achieve that? so it was the first Mon/Tue/Thu/Fri of a month? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
const currentDate = moment(Date.now);
const dayOfMonth = currentDate.date();
const dayOfWeek = currentDate.weekday();

//check if its the first 3 days of the month
  if (dayOfMonth >= 1 && dayOfMonth <= 3) {

//check if its the first of the month and also a weekday
    if (dayOfMonth === 1 && dayOfWeek >= 1 && dayOfWeek <= 5) {
      //set your conditions here
    }

//check if its the 2nd/3rd of the month and also a weekday, if the the 1st/2nd was //on a weekend
    if ((dayOfMonth === 2 || dayOfMonth === 3) && dayOfWeek === 1) {
      //set your conditions here
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but none of your solutions are quite satisfying
if you want the first monday of the next month = month +1..
Do this (but you can convert using xxx? zzz:yyy; notation, I kept it with classic if for readibility)

```html
let first = moment().startOf('month').add(1, 'month');
let day = first;
if ( first.day() > 1 ) {
    day = first.add(8 - first.day(), 'day');
}
if ( day.day() === 0 ) {
    day = day.add(1, 'days');
}
date = day.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```