# moments how to get the last weekday of the last month(december)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i'm following this guide [Get the First Weekday of the Month with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446035/get-the-first-weekday-of-the-month-with-moment-js)

and it works fine to get the first weekday of the first month(January)

but, when i'm trying to use the opposite. i'm getting the last weekday of the month that will be December. i try to change the add in minus and sub but not working

Comment: can you show your js?

Comment: source code or do u mean jsfiddle like that???

Comment: yes Please if you can

Comment: Worth noting that in many places the business week runs from Saturday to Wednesday inclusive and Thursday and Friday are the weekend. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [moment-business-days](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days) for doing business days related processing. It would be much easier if you are doing more of such processing and not just this problem.

```
var moment = require('moment-business-days');

// Set the date for december. You can use this for any month.
// Get array of business days for the month
var businessDays=moment('01-12-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY').monthBusinessDays();

// Get last business day from the array
var lastBusinessDay = businessDays[businessDays.length-1]._d;

console.log(lastBusinessDay);
```

You can see the output [here](https://runkit.com/dushyantbangal/587398b691e409001409b6ff) or clone and edit it.
Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dushyantbangal/yp5pyd05/3/)

Comment: do u have jsfiddle so i can test :)

Comment: I used it in nodejs, I'm not sure how I can add moment-business-days on fiddle

Comment: @wiwit I've added the link

Comment: added fiddle as well

Comment: let me check this :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 var dateFrom = moment().subtract(1, 'months').endOf('month').format("dddd")
alert(dateFrom);
```

For year use this

```
var year = moment().subtract(1, 'months').endOf('month').get('year');
alert(year);
```

use this with format "dddd".

So for business weekday use "moment-business" [library](https://libraries.io/bower/momentjs-business).

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajays871/r42jg/1820/)

Comment: I think by 'weekday', OP means 'Mon-Fri only

Comment: yeah i got saturday and when i edit the format it is 2016 it will be great if we get the latest year :)

Comment: edited my answer for year as well, updated fiddle as well

Answer (score 2):

```
/* 
    get last day of the year and add days:
    0   : if not sunday/saturday
    -2  : if sunday 
    -1  : if saturday 
*/
var eom = moment().utc().endOf('year');
eom.add((eom.day() % 6 !== 0) ? 0 : (eom.day() === 0) ? -2 : -1, 'day');
```

```js
/* Testing for every last week day of the month .. */
var eom = null; /* store end-of-month */ 
var log = '';
var i = 0;

/* loop for all 12 months from jan - dec */
while (i < 12) {
 eom = moment().utc().month(i).endOf('month');
 log = eom.format('LLLL') + ' ~~~ ';

 eom.add((eom.day() % 6 !== 0) ? 0 : (eom.day() === 0) ? -2 : -1, 'day');
 log += eom.format('LLLL');

 console.log(log);
 i++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```