# startOf(string) issue in Angular2 - Momentjs

Tags: angular, date, typescript, momentjs

I'm trying to use Moment.js in Angular2 to get the date of the first day of the week in my TypeScript.

But when I try to use the method startOf(), I got a weird error :

```
moment('2017-07-26').startOf('isoweek');
```

> Argument of type '"isoweek"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StartOf'.

But in the [Moment doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/), and [other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875649/moment-js-starting-the-week-on-monday-with-isoweekday) the signature is correct :

> moment().startOf(String);

Where is my mistake ?

P.S. : Sorry for my bad english and mistakes I probably did. Edit are welcomed, if needed !

Comment: You should use `'isoWeek'` instead of `isoweek`, the parameter is case sensitive, check [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) docs.

Comment: True... Damn... Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget an Uppercase, You should use 'isoWeek' instead of 'isoweek', but it shoud work anyway.

Hope it helps
Peace

Comment: In addition to 'isoWeek', 'isoWeeks' and 'W' should also work. See https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/ts3.1-typings/moment.d.ts#L311.