# Using Momentjs in Angular to find the dates of the current week

Tags: angular, typescript, date, momentjs, dayofweek

I would like to find all five dates of the current week (Mon - fri) in Angular Typescript project using moment.js.
For example
Is Monday is the starting day of this week :-

Monday 22nd March
Tuesday 23rd March
Wednesday 24th March
Thursday 25th March
Friday 26th March

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214442/get-current-week

Comment: Need to be in typescript.

Comment: This is the *very same* in TypeScript. TS is JS with types on top...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214442/get-current-week)

Comment: not really unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it using :

```
  dateMon: moment.Moment; 
  dateTues: moment.Moment; 
  dateWed: moment.Moment; 
  dateThurs: moment.Moment; 
  dateFri: moment.Moment;  


    this.dateMon = moment().weekday(1);
    this.dateTues = moment().weekday(2);
    this.dateWed = moment().weekday(3);
    this.dateThurs = moment().weekday(4);
    this.dateFri = moment().weekday(5);
```