# How to determine which weekdays belong to the weekend depending on the region

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, locale, dayofweek

I must determine which weekdays belong to the weekend in dependence of the region. With MomentJs I can easily find out which day is the first of the week, but the first day of the week is not the first day after the weekend in every region. For example, in the USA and Germany the weekends are Saturday and Sunday, but in the USA the week starts on Sunday and in Germany on Monday.

Is there another way to find that out? Or do I need to customize the locale configurations of MomentJS manually for every region?

```
const day = moment(date).weekday();
if (dayMoment === 5 || dayMoment === 6) {;
     etc...
}
```

Edit: 
I don't want to set the days myself because I want to automatically determine which day is the weekend and which day is the first of the week. The user enters the locale of momentJS.

```
moment.locale('en')
moment.locale('de')
moment.locale('ar')
...
```

Comment: here's what you're looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875953/1703744

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js - Starting the week on Monday with isoWeekday()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875649/moment-js-starting-the-week-on-monday-with-isoweekday)

Comment: I'm not sure my question came across right. I have to find out which days belong to the weekend and on which day the week starts.
I only set the locale of momentjs depending on the user output.

E.g. locale('en'), locale('de'), locale('ar'), ...