# moment.js how to set startOf week to monday on current week?

Tags: node.js, momentjs, adonis.js

I want to make the date of `startOf("week")` its start from Monday on current week

Is it possible for make this? My code:

```
moment().startOf("week").toDate();
```

This `startOf` start from saturday [proof startOf start from saturday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj7DP.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting the week on Monday with isoWeekday()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875649/starting-the-week-on-monday-with-isoweekday)

Comment: nope, the result of iso week its : 2022-03-13T17:00:00.000Z and they still its sunday

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [First Day of Week and First Week of Year](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/dow-doy/) section

From the docs (emphasis is mine)

> Locale#week.dow should be an integer representing the first day of the week, 0 is Sunday, **1 is Monday**, ..., 6 is Saturday.

So just by running this code before doing any calls to moment

```
// From 2.12.0 onward
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    week : {
        dow : 1
    }
});
```

It will set the first day of the week to Monday.

After that calling `moment().startOf("week").toDate()` will give you a Monday.